# Angular 5 keyup error

Tags: angular, events, angular5, keyup

I am getting an error that says

> ERROR TypeError: _co.onKey is not a function
>       at Object.eval [as handleEvent]

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";


@Component({
    selector: "sandbox",
    templateUrl: "sandbox.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./sandbox.component.css"]
})

export class SandboxComponent {
    fireEvent(e){
        console.log(e.type);
    }
}
```

html

```
<input (keyup)="fireEvent($event)">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you just have to add `type="name"` to your input tag.

TS :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
      fireEvent(e){
        console.log(e,e.keyCode);
    }
}
```

HTML :

```
  <input type="name" (keyup)="fireEvent($event)">
```

Sample here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jbym58?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Ahhh that was me rushing, Thanks for letting me know Yanis-git, I'll accept in 5 mins when it allows me.